# Заполнение массива числами с плавающей точкой (Python)

Tags: python, float, round

Нужно заполнить массив числами (допустим, десятью) с плавающей точкой, оставив два знака после запятой.

Пробовал следующее:

```
import random
from array import *
nums=array('f',[])
for i in range(0,10):
    nums.append(round(random.uniform(10,100),2))
for x in nums:
    print(x)
```

Вывод получается все равно неокруглённый:

49.16999816894531
36.060001373291016
80.7300033569336
31.809999465942383
99.93000030517578
52.029998779296875
90.86000061035156
68.77999877929688
83.80999755859375
34.470001220703125

Как исправить и почему это происходит?

Comment: Важно понимать, что ограничить число знаков после запятой возможно только в выводе (т.е. приведении к строковому типу). Используя `round`, вы получаете число, ближайшее к тому, которое ожидаете (`49.16999816894531` вместо `49.17`). Объясняется это тем, что не каждое число может быть представлено типом с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Вам надо почитать про суть чисел с плавающей точкой. Там много приколов, вкратце - это не точные числа, они всегда приблизительные.

Comment: Спасибо, понял: округление будет только в выводе. Если присваивать случайное значение сначала переменной, то при ее выводе все было нормально — пока не делался append этой переменной в массив.